# How does Windows know i am on a 'metered network'?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

When I connect to the mobile WiFi hotspot of my cellphone from my Windows 10 laptop, i get notified that I am on a 'metered network'. Outlook asks me if it should sync emails to avoid high cost. OneDrive does the same.

How does Windows know this hotspot is 'metered'? I can think of several ways how this could be done, but wasn't able to confirm either.

Is there anything special in the DHCP response from the hotspot that indicated metering?

Does Windows know from the public IP I get?

Comment: Windows knows because you hit the checkbox indicating the connection is metered.

Answer (score 3):

[DHCP option 43 - the vendor specified information tag](https://www.lorier.net/docs/android-metered.html). Android for example will put 'ANDROID_METERED' text in there, and Windows can pick that up.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[How can phone companies detect tethering (incl. Wifi hotspot)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47819/how-can-phone-companies-detect-tethering-incl-wifi-hotspot)
has a very good accepted answer that you may consult.
I list below the points that seemed relevant without further details.

- Your phone tells your network that you are tethering
- Inspecting the network packets for their TTL (time to live)
- MAC address inspection
- TCP/IP Stack Fingerprinting